# 2x2 Button Grid layout

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, layout

Im trying to create a layout containing a 2x2 grid of buttons (4 total). Ive got the following however it only creates the button grid in the top left. I want the button grid to fill the whole screen.

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

you should use weight for buttons

Comment: i was so close to answer that too :(

Comment: Thanks! thats clean

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you use a simple RelativeLayout without getting into the hassle of using weights (either with LinearLayout, TableLayout or a combination of both). Here is a sample layout showing how you can achieve a 2 X 2 grid that covers the entire screen using just a RelativeLayout, thereby making it more efficient and faster.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:background="#42A5F5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/one"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:background="#EF5350"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/two"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:background="#66BB6A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/three"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/centerVerticalShim"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerHorizontalShim"
    android:background="#5C6BC0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/four"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView></RelativeLayout>
```

The above layout results in this:
[image]

Comment: This answer is very good and faster and efficent. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is what u are looking for:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way. Try this!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Button 2" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Button 3" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Button 4" />

    </GridLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```