# Slow image replacement in ImageView on hover

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingRight="25dp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- HEAD beginning -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="250px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/labell"
            android:text="Marjan"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- HEAD end -->
    <!-- HR beginning -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
        <View android:id="@+id/primerdivisor"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- HR end -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/qr_states"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/video_white"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image3"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/internet_white"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image4"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/info_white"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

When I hover over one of the four images, I want to replace it with another image. I tried using StateLists, which worked, but there was a very noticeable lag between the replacement. It says in eclipse that I use nested weights, which is probably the reason for the lag.

I tried rewriting the layout using a [2x2 table grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081292/2x2-button-grid-layout) of ImageViews,but that didn't work, since it doesn't resize the images so the four of them would fit on the screen. I'd also like to keep the existing head.

Can someone propose a layout design which would work?

Comment: What do you mean by hover ? Do you use a mouse or you touch screen ?

Comment: Smart glasses, which have a mouse-like cursor. The problem was in the nested weights. I flattened (got rid of) them by using a relative layout.

Comment: Please share code for your StateLists