# android - how to put imageview on top of textview letter?

Tags: android, textview

I've read [an answer from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793282/8002602)

but I want to add some icon on top of each textview

how to do that? any idea?

I've tried using `layout_above`, `layout_below`, etc but it's not what I wish

Edited :

the image size is big, how to set image size after add `android:drawableTop="@drawable/image"`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `android:drawableTop="@drawable/YOUR_DRAWABLE"` its simple.

Comment: what the code of silver in drawable? _**EDIT**_ there's some way to set size of image/icon? or should i resize the image?

Answer (score 0):

To set run time use code -

```
imgView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.imgSrc, 0, 0);
```

here (0, R.drawable.imgSrc, 0, 0) left-top-right-bottom
0 if you don't want to add.

Answer (score 0):

use this on your XML

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
```

or on you Activity class

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.your_image, 0, 0);
textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
```

Comment: there's someway to set size of image?